# how to access the name of group of contacts on phone with flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I need to access the name of groups; the contact picker did work well but only to select a number of contact but not the name of groups that are already on my phone. how to do that please.?

Comment: Please elaborate what you have tried

Comment: well for the contact picker it did work very well i mean picking the name ,phone number, what i need is to access the groups that i have created on my phone list
like on android there is contactscontract.groups , so is there an equivalent for that on flutter?

Comment: how did you solve this problem?